# Removing None's array from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, null

I have numpy array

```
a = np.array([[None, None],[72,10][None,None][77,10]])
```

I would like remove [None, None] from numpy array.

Is there an efficient way to remove Nones array from numpy arrays and resize the array ?

I would like have array:

```
array([72,10],[77,10]])
```

Comment: What behaviour do you want in case one row contains None and integers e.g. `[None, 72]`?

Comment: I have never that example.  I have 100 Mb data.

Comment: `from itertools import starmap

def f(x):
 if x[0]>15:
  return[x[1],x[2]]
 else:
  return [None,None]
output=list(starmap(f, zip(a,b,c))`
output have never that example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing by selecting the rows where all values are not None:

```
out = a[(a!=None).all(1)].astype(int)
```

output:

```
array([[72, 10],
       [77, 10]])
```